# How insert "many to many" data to sqlite on node.js with Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

So, I have this model:

`news`

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var news = sequelize.define('news', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    content: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        news.belongsToMany(models.tags, {
          through: models.tags_in_news,
          foreignKey: 'tags_id'
        })
      }
    }
  });
  return news;
};
```

`tags`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var tags = sequelize.define('tags', {
    tag: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        tags.belongsToMany(models.news, {
          through: models.tags_in_news,
          foreignKey: 'news_id'
        })
      }
    }
  });
  return tags;
};
```

`tags_in_news`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var tags_in_news = sequelize.define('tags_in_news', {
    news_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    tags_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return tags_in_news;
};
```

And i have  not normalized array of news

```
var insertNews = [
  {
    title: "My new 1",
    content: "Content 1 ...",
    tags: [{tag: "tag1"}, {tag: "tag3"}, {tag: "tag5"}]
  },
  {
    title: "My new 2",
    content: "Content 2 ...",
    tags: [{tag: "tag1"}, {tag: "tag2"}, {tag: "tag3"}]
  },
  {
    title: "My new 3",
    content: "Content 3 ...",
    tags: [{tag: "tag3"}, {tag: "tag4"}, {tag: "tag5"}]
  }
]
```

How to best way add data to the database?

Answer (score 0):

By virtue of defining the relationship, you can create news items with tags in one go, so you can do

```
news.create({
    title: 'A news item',
    content: 'Some content',
    tags: [{ tag: 'tag1' }, { tag: 'tag2' }]
}, {
    include: tags
})
```

Comment: Ok. but tags recreated. I need to get from the table tags if they do not exist, then create

Comment: Ooh, OK. Not sure, but try findOrCreate (I haven't tried it with embedded records before)